# Does presentViewController automatically destroy previous views?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, segue

I use a bunch of custom segues to segue from one view controller view to another using:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"createTeamAccountSegue" sender:self];
```

My question is, do the previous views automatically get destroyed in iOS5 and 6?

I keep having to create custom segues to go to the next view, and then create yet another new segue animation in reverse to go back to the last view. As long as they dont keep stacking up and up then this should be fine right?

EDIT: I should probably show you the general layout of what my custom UIStoryboardSegue class looks like:

```
- (void) perform {

UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *destinationViewController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

UIView *parent = sourceViewController.view.superview;

[parent addSubview:destinationViewController.view];
[parent sendSubviewToBack:destinationViewController.view];

sourceViewController.view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
sourceViewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 8; // if you like rounded corners
sourceViewController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
sourceViewController.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
sourceViewController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;

destinationViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, destinationViewController.view.frame.size.width, destinationViewController.view.frame.size.height);
sourceViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, sourceViewController.view.frame.size.width, sourceViewController.view.frame.size.height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^
 {
     sourceViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, parent.frame.size.height, sourceViewController.view.frame.size.width, sourceViewController.view.frame.size.height);

 } completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
 }];
```

}

Comment: Ah! Giving back! I will do so :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing there segues in a UINavigationController then no, they aren't destroyed. To go back to one you should use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: My inital view controller is a UINavigationController -> Root View Controller that checks to see if the user is logged in, it then uses custom segues with presentViewController to display either the login view or the logged in view.

Is there any problems doing this?

Comment: There are lots of ways to lay this out. I prefer to present a modal view controller with a delegate method on the root controller that is called if login is successful, or if an API key is set in NSUserDefaults. That way you can treat the login process as something that is in fact modal ie. requires action, and the rest of your app is considered to be a normal flow of pushing and popping viewcontrollers.

Comment: I can't help but feel i'm doing something wrong with custom segues. My storyboard looks like this and has segues back and forth, instead of one like on other storyboards i see: http://i.imgur.com/nThGo.png

Comment: You don't need the transition back.  Just create segue to the login screen, choose style "modal" and set your login button action to call     [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: The problem is that the views need to have custom animations, and modal only supply a few basic ones

Comment: If you want to do something like a page turn or a flip you can use the non modal transitions and use the button action to call  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Your segues push viewcontrollers onto a stack managed by the navigationcontroller, so to reverse that you should pop.